# angular - show values in html table ngFor just for specific objects

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working on a web application using angular with typescript for frontend and I have a list of orders which I am displaying into a table in html. What I want to do is when I click on a button to show the products contained in the order. I managed to do something, but my solution displays the products for all the orders instead of just the one ordered I clicked the button for.

This is my html file:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table" *ngFor="let order of orders;">
                <tr>
                  <td id="tag"> <b>Comanda cu numărul:</b></td>
                  <td>{{order.number}}</td>
                  <td id="date"><b>Data:</b></td>
                  <td>{{order.date}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td id="tag"><b>Statusul comenzii:</b></td>
                  <td>{{order.status}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td id="tag"><b>Total de plată:</b></td>
                  <td>{{order.totalPrice}} lei</td>
                  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td (click)="seeOrdersProducts()">
                    Vezi detalii comandă
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tbody *ngIf="seeProducts% 2 != 0">
                  <tr *ngFor="let product of order.products">
                    <td>
                      <img src="{{product.picture}}" width="30" height="30" style="float:right;" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" [routerLink]="['/view-product', product.id]">{{product.name}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      {{product.price | currency:'RON'}}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
```

I am using a variable in .ts file to track the clicking of the button, so if you click once it will show the products, if you click the second time it will hide the products, this is the function that increments the variable everytime a button is clicked:

```
   seeOrdersProducts() {
    this.seeProducts++;
  }
```

So this is how it looks like initially:

[initial view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7g3D.png)

And this is how it looks after any button of "Vezi detalii comanda" is clicked:

[view after clicking the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HDRc.png)

So what I would need is when I click the button (which is basically a  tag with a click function) for the first order to drill down only the products for that order, without drilling down the details for all other orders.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe strange solution but it could works. You can create one array which contains the orders that need to be displayed. If order is in array you display the products. Here is my snippet.

ts

```js
let ordersToDisplay: Order[] = [];
...
seeOrdersProducts(order: Order) {
   this.ordersToDisplay.push(order);
}
```

html

```html
<tr>
 <td (click)="seeOrdersProducts(order)">
    Vezi detalii comandă
 </td>
</tr>
<tbody *ngIf="ordersToDisplay.includes(order)">
     ....
</tbody>
```

Of course if you want to close products, it needs more code.